# Page dissapears when i click save

Tags: themes

So when i click save in a WP page the page content disappear.
While it is still in Draft mode i can preview the content ok, thus it disappears when i click the Publish button.
I have discovered that this happens only with the active Theme. If i change Theme the problem stops. Also there is no conflict with Plugins.
What could cause such behavior?
The console displays nothing.
The php error log says:

```
[06-Oct-2019 09:49:40 UTC] PHP Warning:  call_user_func_array() 
expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 
'webp_express_uninstall' not found or invalid function name in 
/opt/lampp/htdocs/mywpwebsite/wordp$
```

Comment: In this platform asking for help other than WordPress Core is discouraged and off-topic too. So everybody here will simply say "Change your theme".

Comment: ah ok thought it would be relevant. Could you please suggest another platform?

Comment: Best would be to contact directly with the theme author using their support channel/forum etc.

Comment: What i am asking here is if this rings a bell on a PHP context.

Comment: Not a all. Because function `webp_express_uninstall()` is not from WP Core, and that prefix `webp_` is might be from the theme. It's saying, _that_ particular function is missing. As it's not from WP Core, the question is off-topic here. Referring to the [FAQ].